# How to run JavaFX Window in other Class

Tags: class, javafx, window

as in title, i need help with Running JavaFX in other class. For exmaple, from Main i want to type something like 'new TempClass()' and then i expect new Window but i got nothing xD Thank you in advance for solve the problem! <3

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        new TempClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); // when i launch(args) the 'start' func starting btw
    }
}
```

TempClass:

```
public class TempClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(300,300);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very strange situation. What are you trying to accomplish? One `Application` is all that is needed to handle multiple windows. Do you really need to start a brand new application or just open a new window?

Comment: Perhaps reading a couple more JavaFX tutorials will help you understand the basic flow of an Application.

Comment: `Application` classes are used as entry point and only one of them can be used with `Application.launch` for each run. It'd be best to move the logic to a class not extending `Application`, if you want to create an application from different "Parts". Delegating to a different `Application` class imho is pointless, but you need to call the lifecycle methods (`start`, also `init` and `stop`, if those are overwritten in the second `Application` class) of the second `Application` class on your own, IF you want to do this properly.

Comment: Well, thank you all for comments, i've found a correct way to do what i want! :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of few ways which solved my problem:

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(TempClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

TempClass:

```
public class TempClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(300,300);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```